# Mounted NTFS windows-linux shared partition works for users r-w, but access denied for programs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount, ntfs

I created an NTFS partition to share my data between my two OS : Kubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.
I tried several fstab configs :

`UUID=partitionId /media/totok/Data ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatume,allow_other 0 0`

`UUID=partitionId /media/totok/Data ntfs-3g defaults,user,rw,umask=000,dmask=000,fmask=000,uid=1000,gid=100,windows_names 0 0`

`UUID=partitionId /media/totok/Data ntfs-3g rw,nodev,exec,nouser,async,suid,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0`

With all these configs, I have read/write access to the partition with the user totok (uid 1000), but when I want to open a file with a software, i've got an `Access Denied` error.

Wierdest thing : it happens with some softwares, but not all (eg : happens with Gimp, installed with snapd, but not with VSCode or Kate)

I already deactivated Windows Fast boot.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I also tried `UUID=partitionId /media/totok/Data ntfs-3g rw,permissions 0 2`, but same.
I tried to reinstall the snap programs I have with the --classic option, but no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that the programs that didn't have the permissions were snap programs installed without the --classic parameter. Without this, they are clustered in their directory and have only access to the home directories. The only workaround I found was to remove these applications and install them manually with apt / with the *.deb packages.
I will continue to use snap for programs that didn't need to access data partition / that can be installed with --classic option (eg. jetbrains suite)

Answer (score 0):

If a program opens the file for writing right away (even though it should only read at that point), it needs more permissions than a program that only reads. Then there is the need to create a lockfile or a temporary file (in the application's native format). You may lack permission to write to some locations.

(typo in your text: "noatume")

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I retried with the good typo, didn't solve the problem.
How can i check if your explanation is the source of the problem ?
I tried to open a file from Gimp (file -> open), I can navigate though my home, but I can't access the /media folder. Navigating though folders doesn't need lock file, isn't it ? I'm a bit lost here...